# How to add AM/PM to Bootstrap Material DatePicker

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, material-design

I am trying to add AM/PM to **bootstrapMaterialDatePicker**, I set **twelvehour: true** but nothing seemed to work. How do i add AM/PM because on my device, those aren't options and it instead uses a 24 hour clock?

```
$('.timer').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker
            ({
                date: false,
                shortTime: false,
                format: 'HH:mm',
                twelvehour: true
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "format" is set to `HH:mm`, however, to get the 12-hour format with am/pm at the end, you'll need to use `hh:mm a` as format<sup>[[1]](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/)</sup>. Furthermore, "twelvehour" isn't a valid option for the bootstrapMaterialDatePicker function<sup>[[2]](https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker#parameters)</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `a` to your format `HH:mm a` and set the value `shortTime: true` 
to show the AM/PM in your GUI to allow the user to select it

```
  // Bootstrap timepicker
  $('.timer').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
     date: false,
     shortTime: true,
     twelvehour: false,
     format: 'HH:mm a'
  });
```